# Prove that there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tan2x\cot3x\in\left(\frac23,9\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tan2x\cot3x\in\left(\frac23,9\right)$
I tried to write write $\tan2x$ and $\tan3x$ in terms of $\tan x$ and then to solve inequalities $\frac{\tan2x}{\tan3x}>\frac23$ and $\frac{\tan2x}{\tan3x}<9$ separately. It looks very hard to do this. Is there any easier method?

Comment: Have you tried reducing everything to $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ and eventually writing it in terms of $\cos x$ - which should be possible because your function is an even trigonometric function $[f(x)=f(-x)]$?

Comment: It is easier to write it in terms of $\tan x$, but it is still hard to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sketch

With a bit of work this reduces to $$\frac{8\cos^4 x-6\cos^2 x}{8\cos^4 x-6\cos^2 x+1}$$

Writing $c=\cos x$ with $-1\le c\le 1$, and multiplying numerator and denominator by $8$ this becomes $$\frac {(8c^2-3)^2 -9}{(8c^2-3)^2 -1}$$

Now if $y=(8c^2-3)^2$ we have $0\le y\le 25$ and $$f(y)=\frac {y-9}{y-1}=1-\frac 8{y-1}$$

and that is easy enough to work with.

Answer (score 1):

if we write $2\xi^{-1} = \frac{\tan 2x}{\tan 3x}$ and $t=\tan x $, then we have:
$$
\xi = \frac{(1-t^2)(3-t^2)}{1-3t^2}
$$this gives a quadratic equation for $\alpha = t^2$:

$$
\alpha^2 -(4-3\xi)\alpha + (3-\xi) =0
$$

the condition in the question amounts to the requirement that this equation has a real non-negative root. use the standard solution:

$$
2\alpha = (4-3\xi) \pm \sqrt{(9\xi-2)(\xi-2)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $\cos^2x=t\ (0\le t\le 1)$, we have
$$\tan(2x)\cot(3x)=\frac{8t^2-6t}{(4t-1)(2t-1)}=f(t),\ \ \ \ f'(t)=\frac{2(8t-3)}{(4t-1)^2(2t-1)^2}.$$
Here, note that $t\not=0,\frac 14,\frac 12.$

Then, noting that
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(t)=0,\ \lim_{t\to \frac 14\pm0}f(t)=\pm\infty,\ \lim_{t\to \frac 12\pm0}f(t)=\mp\infty$$
and that 
$$f\left(\frac 38\right)=9,\ \ f(1)=\frac 23,$$
these lead the conclusion as desired.

Comment: Your solution is understandable, but I must prove it without using derivatives and limits.